# How to disable the control in Custom Wizard (Custom Project Template) for Visual Studio (Visual C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, project-template

I want to disable by default some of the controls in the Project Wizard created with [Custom Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhceedxx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in Visual Studio 2013 (Visual C++).

The code:

```
<input class="CheckBox" type="checkbox" id="BOX1" title="Box 1">
```

creates a checkbox.

So I've tried both:

```
<input class="CheckBox" type="checkbox" id="BOX1" title="Box 1" disabled>
```

and:

```
<input class="CheckBox" type="checkbox" id="BOX1" 
    title="Box 1" disabled="disabled">
```

But none of them worked (checkbox is still enabled).

I was even trying including JS:

```
alert('JS works'); //alert occured (indeed, JS works in general)
document.getElementById("BOX1").disabled = true; //did not work
```

**So, how to disable that control?**

For the example, here the "Use HTML dialog" is disabled, and I want to get the same effect on my control (the screenshot is from MFC wizard, but it doesn't matter):

[image]

Comment: Curious to know why you've not looked at the source for the example wizard that you reference... you're asking the question "why doesn't A work like B", and not actually looking at how B works.

Comment: @icabod I was searching throw documentation of Visual Studio and not throw the code itself (I thought it's somewhere there, the sample I've created was made with the help of MSDN page). It may look silly to you, but I was under impression, that "disabled control" is something so common that it should be well documented without a need to look into source code. But now I agree, looking at sample's source was the way to go.

Comment: It should all be documented, I agree, and in theory your method should work.  MS provides all of the wizards it uses (usually), so just take a look at the one that does what you want.  It's like a built-in tutorial :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm basing my answer on an older version of Visual Studio (2010) which probably has a different Wizard system, but at least it's an answer...

Looking at the MFC AppWizard, the method for creating the (by-default disabled) checkbox is to have a basic checkbox with a name (in this case `HTML_DIALOG`).  The wizard HTML has an `onload` method that calls some JScript to initialise the page with your required default settings:

```
function InitDocument(document) {
  ...
  HTML_DIALOG.disabled = true;
  HTML_DIALOG_LABEL.disabled = true;
  ...
}
```

The Visual Studio app wizards are generally located under you base VS install directory, in (for example) `VC\VCWizards`. The MFC AppWizard I referenced above is even deeper, under (for my install and locale) `AppWiz\MFC\Application\html\1033`. The exact path may vary depending on version and language.

For your example, you could go the following route, if that's the only item you want to default-disable:

```
<body ... onload="BOX1.disable=true;">
```

Otherwise call an onload method:

```
<body ... onload="initialise(document);">
   ...
</body>
<script language="JSCRIPT">
  function initialise(document) {
    BOX1.disabled = true;
    BOX1_label.disabled = true;
  }
</script>
```

As I say, that's based on VS2010, and also completely untested, but from that I get the impression that your HTML tags themselves shouldn't contain defaults, they are set after the HTML has loaded.  This approach actually gives you more scope to "tweak" the defaults based on parameters.  I guess.

Comment: It may sounds lame, but... where the MFC AppWizard code (that you are quoting) is located? I mean, where can I physically find the .html, .vcxproj etc. files for it? Anyway, I will award the answer asap (I cannot do it in few hours).

Comment: @PolGraphic Have a look in the Visual Studio install directory, probably under `VC\VCWizards`. The file I looked at was deeper, under `AppWiz\MFC\Application\html\1033`. Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks - now I've all I needed :) P.S. Can you move that comment into an answer - the comments are being erased sometimes and I guess that path can be an useful note to the answer.